# How to populate data in one table from another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

i have two tables in my toll database in MySQL, namely **traffic_shift_wise** and **traffic_day_wise**. And the columns of these tables are as follows:

Table **traffic_shift_wise**

```
toll_id    date         shift    car_single    car_return    car_total
1          2016-09-01   1        25            10            35
1          2016-09-01   2        50            25            75
1          2016-09-02   1        100           50            150
1          2016-09-02   2        200           100           300
```

**traffic_day_wise**

```
toll_id    date            car_single       car_return      car_total
1          2016-09-01      75               35              110
1          2016-09-02      300              150             450
```

There are two shifts in day for a specific toll, here you can see that i have to take data from the **traffic_shift_wise** to **traffic_day_wise**, automatically just after insert in **traffic_shift_wise**.

So, please help me out with this. What should i use, triggers.. ?

Comment: yes, you have to use triggers to update data in traffic_day_wise

Comment: @HappyCoding so ok i understand that i have to use trigger but what will be the exact query to do this, like you can see that in the **traffic_day_wise** i need to transfer data group by date.

Comment: We help with problems, we do not write your code for you. Google for the `create trigger` syntax, then create your statements as needed. Have a look at `if...else`, `insert` and `update`. You check first, if an entry for this day exists. If not, you insert, else you update the entry. Go ahead, have a try, come back if you encounter problems. Learning by doing, not copying ;-) Good excercise for learning. But actually I think you should simply use a `view` instead of another table.